# Error while trying to delete multiple values from the DB in a loop using Sequelize

Tags: angularjs, sequelize.js

I am trying to delete values selected by the user in a loop.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            MyService.myMapService.delete({id: myArray[i].myId }, myArray[i], function (response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        MyService.removeMyValue(myArray[i].myId);
                    }
            })
        }
```

However, I keep receiving the following error

> angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'myId' of
>   undefined

Please help!

Comment: what do you have in myArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happening is, your for loop is getting executed for all `MyService.myMapService.delete` function call and your `i` is becoming `myArray.length`. There after when `myMapService.delete` async call completed, it tries to do `myArray[i].myId`(where i is array length, then `myArray[i]` would be undefined). In this case you have to preserve value of by wrapping it to self executing function.

**Code**

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  (function(j) {
    MyService.myMapService.delete({
      id: myArray[j].myId
    }, myArray[j], function(response) {
      if (response.isSuccessful) {
        MyService.removeMyValue(myArray[j].myId);
      }
    })
  })(i);
}
```